# RailsTutorial: Why is there always some session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, railstutorial.org

I am following [Railstutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org). Now at Chapter 8 where it talks about session.
I am trying to verify session cookie is destroyed everytime user logs out

I am using Firebug->cookie tab to verify that.
But I notice there is always some session whether I login or not.

The only difference I noticed was that there is new session id before login, after valid login and after logout.

So my question is why is there some session everytime

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently following the Railstutorial as well and have been wondering this myself. I assume you're referring to this exercise in the tutorial (section 8.3):

> 2. By checking the site cookies, confirm that the session is correctly
>      removed after logging out.

The way I read it, this implies that the session cookie should be removed after logout, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I couldn't really find specific information on this online, so I quickly set up an empty Rails app to see if it would set cookies, too. Lo and behold, apparently every Rails app automagically creates a session cookie, even when you don't do anything session-related in your app-specific code.

This doesn't answer what exactly Rails stores in that cookie, but at least I'm not going crazy. I think the exercise should be removed or at least changed.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are used to keep miscellaneous data for your application's users.

Their existence shouldn't depend on whether your users are signed in or not.

For example, a weather website asking users to select their metric system, should be able to remember their choice without requiring them to sign in first.

Of course there are other reasons to always have a session assigned to your users (like logging etc).